# How do I perform _hashTypedDataV4 on a struct containing an array of structs

Tags: struct, hash, keccak, ecrecover, eip712

I have signed a typed data, and I am trying to recover the address of the signer from my contract using ECDSA.recover(). But each time I try it, I get an address that is different from the address of the original signer. I have a very strong feeling that the problem is from the result I get when I hash the struct is hashed.

Now the struct is in this format:

```
struct Info {
  uint256 val1;
  address val2;
}

struct Document {
  address from;
  address to;
  Info[] data1;
  Info[] data2;
  bytes signature;
}
```

And this is the content of my _hash function:

```
function _hash(Document calldata data) internal view returns (bytes32) {
    
    return _hashTypedDataV4(keccak256(abi.encode(
      keccak256("Document(address from,address to,Info[] data1,Info[] data2)Info(uint256 val1,address val2)"),
      data.from,
      data.to,
      keccak256(abi.encode(data.data1)),
      keccak256(abi.encode(data.data2))
    )));
  }
```

I'd like to know if this is the ideal way for hashing a struct containing an array of structs.

Comment: ever figure this out?